# How to integrate spark cluster with other Hadoop2.x cluster on Docker

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker

I have Hadoop2.5 cluster already installed on my server, **running on docker**, and we have a Spark standalone cluster running on the same server(also deployed with docker), how can I swith the Spark cluster from standalone mode to *Spark on Yarn*, since hadoop and spark running on seperated docker.

Comment: Is Spark installed on docker is Spark-Prebuilt with Hadoop 2.5. If you so update the yarn-site.xml and run your program with master = yarn-client/custer.

Comment: Could you share how both clusters configured first, what ports are open, etc